# creating a separated file containing parameters

Tags: matlab, variables, global-variables

I'm a newbie of Matlab's world and I'm trying to create my first simulation with this powerful software. I would put in a unique m file all parameters of my application.I have read somewhere I have to initialize all the variable as global so they can be used anywhere but after that, those variables will be automatically availables in all others my m files situated in the same folder of parameters files, simply calling them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share variables that would otherwise be out of scope of a function, you can declare a function like this

```
function globalFun
global var1 var2
var1 = 5; 
var2 = 6;
```

. . . and then call it from a script like this . . .

```
global var1 var2
var1 = 0; 
var2 = 0;
globalFun
```

You will see that the values are updated in the workspace, even though the function returns no output.

However, in doing this, you are opening up the potential for debugging hell! If you need to pass around a lot of variables between functions and you don't want to write functions with massive argument lists, consider using structures instead. Replace `gloabalFun` with . .

```
function s = structFun(s)    
s.var1 = 5; 
s.var2 = 6;
```

and then call it like so . .

```
s.var1 = 0; 
s.var2 = 0;
s = structFun(s);
```

This way, you can always see at a glance which functions are modifying what.